# jQuery UI Accordion displays properly on one sever but not on another - why?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am just beginning a new site and I am using jQuery UI Accordion for the sidebar navigation. It works great on my computer. It works good on my server, but when I moved it to my clients server this morning, the Accordion breaks - a bit of a flat tire.

I double-checked the paths to jQuery and the css but can't see what is wrong.

Here is the one that works: http://www.rouviere.com/clients/ima/

Here is the one that doesn't: http://imadesign.com/dev/

Here is the html:

```
 <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">principals</a></h3>
            <div>
                <p>bill schulz<br />
                    ron izumita<br />
                    ann cutner<br />
                    leo o'brian</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">senior associates</a></h3>
            <div>
                <p>steve garcia<br />
                    vicki hill<br />
                    glenn ho<br />
                    robert moffat</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">associates</a></h3>
            <div>associates.</div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end accordion -->
```

I would appreciate a careful eye or two to have a look and see if you can tell what is missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and JavaScript is different between pages, for example:

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

and

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3"});
```

Compare the source for a full list of differences in the JavaScript/HTML, using diff from the command prompt or compare in Notepad++ for example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there something that could be removing that? I looked at the file on the server and it is the same, but in the page source it is removed.

Comment: @fmz can you please double check you're looking at the two different sites? If I use wget or check the HTTP server responses in firebug the pages **are** different.

Comment: Hi Raoul. The pages are different, you are right, however, there is something funny happening. On the Not Working page this code is being stripped out of the jQuery: header: "h3" it is there in the file on the server, but it is somehow removed when the page displays.

Comment: @fmz is the server side scripting the same on both sites? that is to say is it performing some manipulation which may cause this to be removed?

Comment: If you look in firebug the not working page has "transfer encoding: chunked". Can you ensure the server side setup (apache, php(?) scripting) is the same

Comment: Raoul, the one difference is that the not working page is part of an Expression Engine site so it is being processed differently, but the basic page content is the same.

Comment: I have no experience of Expression Engine. You'd need to investigate that further, perhaps take it up with their people. My advice is that your dev environment should be the same as production. with such different environments it's hard (as you see) to find the root cause of some problems.

Comment: Raoul, I appreciate your insights. I'll close this out and investigate this other issue. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the HTML being different here's a snippet from both

Working

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#">principals</a></h3>
```

Not Working

```
<h3><a href="#">principals</a></h3>
```

Notice the not working doesn't even have a class list on the h3 (i found the same thing on the div element above it)... so Maybe making the html the same would work.

Comment: The class should be applied dynamically from the jQuery. If you look at the page source they are same.